# EF Core 3 Nested Value Conversion Cannot be Translated

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

### Update

The crux of the issue is caused by using a nested field on a property inside the `where` clause; I've provided a simplified example (which fails with the same "cannot be translated" error) for illustration. For fuller picture, read the content under the Original heading.

The following clause (rest of the query was working before I started using this nested property)

```cs
where (r.Status.IntVal == (int)StatusEnum.Answered) // IntVal is just an int
```

gets translated at runtime to

```cs
.Where(ti => ti.Outer.Status.IntVal == 1) // right hand side translates as expected
```

So the question is: How do you write a proper `ValueConverter` (or what other step do you take) in order to properly read and evaluate a nested field like this in EntityFramework?

### Orginal Post

I recently updated a field on one of my EF models (using EF Core v3.1.3) from an `enum` to a class which has a `System.Enum` field on it. Because I want the database / EF to treat that field as the underlying integer value (like it does with `enum`) I'm using `.HasConversion()` in the fluent API, but I'm getting the dreaded "could not be translated" error.
The following line is the code in the query which is causing the issue

```cs
...
where (r.Status.Value == StatusEnum.Answered || r.Status.Value == StatusEnum.AwaitingResponse)
...
```

which gets translated to

```cs
.Where(ti => (int)ti.Outer.Status.Value == 1 || (int)ti.Outer.Status.Value == 0)
```

The value it is trying to translate is of this type:

```cs
    public class MyStatusClass<T> where T : Enum
    {
        public MyStatusClass(int i)
        {
            Value = (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value.ToString());
            IntVal = i // This was added to simplify problem, see update above
        }

        public T Value { get; internal set; } // This is the field that I need stored in the database

        public int IntVal {get; internal set; } // This was added to simplify problem, see update above

        // Some other methods in here; the reason I converted from an enum to this class               
    }
```

The conversion in my DbContext ModelBuilder looks like this

```cs
entity.Property(x => x.Status)
    .HasConversion(
        status => status.Value,
        status => new StatusClass((int)status) // This is the part to focus on, as its' the part that tells EF how to read the property from the database
    );
```

Comment: Don't use a nested field. You don't need it to begin with. EF Core doesn't do magic, it translates LINQ queries to SQL. The question is unclear though. What are you trying to do? Map enums by name? Or by value? By value is the current behavior. By name can be done with a value converter. This scenario is used as an example in the [Value Converter documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions)

Comment: I'm not sure that conclusion can be made; the reason for doing this is so I can abstract away a lot of the functionality related to the the `Status` field, which is shared by multiple models in my database.

Comment: Abstract *what* functionality? What are you trying to do? What is `MyStatusClass` supposed to be or map to? EF is an ORM - an Object to Relational Mapper. What is `MyStatusClass` mapping to ?

Comment: Business logic that needs to occur when changes to the Status field occur. Each model has its own enum (ala the `StatusEnum`) for the possible values for Status, but a lot of steps in common (notifications etc.). Abstracting that up to the model itself would requiring adding a generic constraint to the model (so the compiler knew which StatusEnum to use for each model) and if I had multiple such fields, multiple constraints, etc.

Comment: You're still describing what you think the solution is, not what the *problem* is. If an Enum isn't enough, you need to use and map a proper class. Entities don't have steps though, *workflows* and *processes* do. EF deals with data entities, not business entities. You can only use the same class for both for simple appications. Once you start using complex logic, the data and business entities have to separate. APIs, vies, resources, business, data are all different domains requiring different models.

Comment: Understood, and I have BL classes to represent the workflows which act on the entities, I'm just trying to share functionality where possible. I guess it would be better to make `Status` a generic enum and move the shared logic out of the `StatusClass` into a BL class. I'm overcomplicating the model and making it not fully represent what's in the database.

Comment: Enums aren't generic, they're just labels on integers. And again, EF deals with data entities, so there's no "generic enum with logic". There are entities, owned/value types, and a special case, enums, that are essentially tagged integers. If you want a `StatusClass` you should map your data entities to your business entities, eg using AutoMapper. It was built for just such cases.

Comment: Check [Web API: Resource Model isn’t your Data Model](https://codeopinion.com/web-api-resource-model-isnt-data-model) where Derek Comartin expands on [Mark Amundsen's tweet](https://twitter.com/mamund/status/767212233759657984?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E767212233759657984%7Ctwgr%5E%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fcodeopinion.com%2Fweb-api-resource-model-isnt-data-model%2F) `your data model is not your object model is not your resource model is not your message model `